# Junit5 @ParameterizedTest How to pass array as one of parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, resttemplate, junit5

I have a test in which I want to pass three parameters:

1. String
2. Enum
3. Array of Strings

Example:

```
@ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({
            "/path/to/first/file.xlsx, FIRST, {THIRD PARAMETER SHOULD BE ARRAY OF STRINGS}",
            "/path/to/second/file.xlsx, SECOND, {THIRD PARAMETER SHOULD BE ARRAY OF STRINGS}"})
    void uploadFile(String path, FileType type, String[] errors) {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = prepareFileUploadEntity(path, type);

        ResponseEntity<ArrayList> response = getRestTemplate(AppRole.USER).exchange(UPLOAD_URL, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, ArrayList.class);

        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, response.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(errors.length, response.getBody().size());
        for (String error : errors) {
            assertTrue(response.getBody().contains(error));
        }
    }
```

How can I pass the third parameter as an array of strings, cause now I have the error that third parameter can`t be resolved:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error resolving parameter at index 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small correction, in

```
return ((String) source).split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

should be a different sign (e.g. ';') instead of ','

Then in test should be

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource("abc, 123, foo; bar")
```

---

Final version which works for me:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.converter.ArgumentConversionException;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.converter.SimpleArgumentConverter;

public class StringArrayConverter extends SimpleArgumentConverter {

    @Override
    protected Object convert(Object source, Class<?> targetType) throws ArgumentConversionException {
        if (source instanceof String && String[].class.isAssignableFrom(targetType)) {
            return ((String) source).split("\\s*;\\s*");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Conversion from " + source.getClass() + " to "
                                               + targetType + " not supported.");
        }
    }

}
```

Test:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource("abc, 123, foo; bar")
void test(String column1, int column2, @ConvertWith(StringArrayConverter.class) String[] column3) {
    assertEquals(column1, "abc");
    assertEquals(column2, 123);
    assertEquals(column3[0], "foo");
    assertEquals(column3[1], "bar");
}
```

Comment: "correction" not needed. 
In my opinion it is best to indicate the "array" as in Kapep answer inside a single quoted string

Answer (score 22):

`@CsvSource` uses [implicit conversion](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-argument-conversion-implicit) to convert CSV values to primitives, Enums or Dates. For other types like Arrays, you need [explicit conversion](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-argument-conversion-explicit).

Assuming you have a CSV annotation in a format like `@CsvSource("abc, 123, 'foo, bar'")`, you can implement an argument converter like this to treat the last CSV column as an array:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.converter.ArgumentConversionException;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.converter.SimpleArgumentConverter;

public class StringArrayConverter extends SimpleArgumentConverter {

    @Override
    protected Object convert(Object source, Class<?> targetType) throws ArgumentConversionException {
        if (source instanceof String && String[].class.isAssignableFrom(targetType)) {
            return ((String) source).split("\\s*,\\s*");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Conversion from " + source.getClass() + " to "
                                               + targetType + " not supported.");
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can use that converter on the third argument:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource("abc, 123, 'foo, bar'")
void test(String column1, int column2, @ConvertWith(StringArrayConverter.class) String[] column3) {
    assertEquals(column1, "abc");
    assertEquals(column2, 123);
    assertEquals(column3[0], "foo");
    assertEquals(column3[1], "bar");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do something like this:

```
@DisplayName("Should rotate successfully")
@ParameterizedTest()
@CsvSource({
        "'[0, 0, 0]', 5, '[0, 0, 0]', false",
})
void givenAnArrayAndAShiftSize_ShouldSuccesfullyRotateOrReturnFalse(String arrayStr, int shiftSize,
        String expectedArrayStr, boolean expecetedRotated) {

    var window = Arrays.asList(arrayStr.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(","))
            .stream()
            .mapToLong(c -> Long.parseLong(c.toString().trim()))
            .toArray();

    var result = Arrays.asList(expectedArrayStr.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(","))
            .stream()
            .mapToLong(c -> Long.parseLong(c.toString().trim()))
            .toArray();

    var rotated = Utils.shiftIfSizeIsValid(window, shiftSize);

    assertEquals(expecetedRotated, rotated);

    for (int i = 0; i < window.length; i++) {
        assertEquals(result[i], window[i]);
    }
}
```

It is simpler and more readable.